# How to get touch events when the user is typing with a soft keyboard on Android

Tags: android

In a research project I need to obtain the touch event when the user is typing with a soft keyboard. It is possible if I draw a soft keyboard on a imageView and set a touchListener for the imageView, but then I will have to figure out which key the user is typing on. Basically I am reimplementing the soft keyboard. So I was wondering if there is a way that I can set a touchListener for the view of the existing soft keyboard and get both the touch event and the text?

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably want to use a KeyEvent see this: 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html

Comment: “As soft input methods can use multiple and inventive ways of inputting text, there is no guarantee that any key press on a soft keyboard will generate a key event”

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look on this post: [button events in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5154711/button-events-in-android)

You can find the equivalent class for key events: /android.hci.extractor/src/org/mmi/android/instrumentation/filters/KeyInputFilter.java

The source code is here: 
 - Android HCI Extractor code: http://code.google.com/p/android-hci-extractor/

I hope it helps you!!

Answer (score -2):

I used this event for that:

```
public void onPress(int primaryCode)
```